# How can I insert alternate blank lines into a table with Python?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a simple (but huge) CSV table, and I need to insert a free (=blank) line/row after each line/row of this table. To explain it in another way, I want every second line of my table to be blank (but without deleting/overwriting any of the original lines). I have tried a lot of ways, but this is the best I could come up with:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input:
   readie=csv.reader(input, delimiter=',')
   with open("output.csv", 'wt', newline='') as output:
       outwriter=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
       for row in readie:
           row_plus = (row, \n)
           outwriter.writerow(row_plus)
```

It doesn't seem to work because it crams all the columns in the table into one column and interprets `(row, \n)` as two columns only. It also just prints "\n" and doesn't recognize that I want it to insert another line break.

Comment: sample input ? expected output?

Comment: @Frank: When `input` is a file opened for `csv.reader`, then you should add the `newline=''` argument to the `output(...)` function -- the same way as you do it for the `outwriter`.  This is rather different situation when compared with your previous question where the values were extracted from the text line read normally from the input file.  I have corrected the indentation in your question.  You should know that you can combine the two `width` constructs into one in Python 3.1+ -- see examples at http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
  for row in readie:
     outwriter.writerow(row)
     outwriter.writerow([])
```

Seems to do what you want.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thanks larsks!