# Insert blank rows every fifth row in csv file python

Tags: python, csv

As my title says i want to insert blank rows in my csv file on every fifth row. The problem is that my code inserts 5 blank rows on every row. Other solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555909/how-can-i-insert-alternate-blank-lines-into-a-table-with-python) on stackoverflow does not solve my problem.

```
What i want:
1 text on row
2 text on row
3 text on row
4 text on row
5 blank

What i get:
1 


 text on row
2


 text on row
etc.
```

My code looks like this:

```
with open("new.csv", 'r') as infile:
   readie=csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
   with open("output.csv", 'wt') as output:
       outwriter=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
       sum = 0
       i = 0
       for row in readie:
            sum == row
            if sum % 5 == 0:
                row_plus = (row, '\n')
                outwriter.writerow(row_plus)
```

Comment: What is the point of `sum += i`? `i` isn't changing at all.

Comment: `sum == row` is weird too.

Comment: Oops, forgot old code with sum +=.

Comment: The point of sum == row was that i could not perform the modulo action on the row variable for some reason.

Comment: You shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name. `sum` is a built-in function in python. Also, `a == b` is to check if `a` is equal to `b`, not for assigning `a` to `b`

Comment: You can't modulo row because it's not an integer, it's one row of the csv file, which I believe is a list. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader says "Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No automatic data type conversion is performed."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
with open("new.csv", 'r') as infile:
    readie=csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',')
    with open("output.csv", 'wt') as output:
        outwriter=csv.writer(output, delimiter=',')
        i = 0
        for row in readie:
             outwriter.writerow(row)
             i += 1
             if i % 5 == 0:
                 # write the empty row
                 outwriter.writerow([])
```